# How to enable the EHCache based ACL Caching in Grails Spring Security ACL Plugin?

Tags: grails, spring-security

We are using the Grails Spring Security ACL Plugin for managing the ACLs on our Domain Classes. Occasionally we've to display lists of these Domain Classes, which have to respect the ACL. The Problem is, once there're several hundred items in a list, the ACL checking of each item makes rendering such lists painfully slow.

I've seen there's a `EhCacheBasedAclCache` Class which seems to provide a solution for this problem, but I haven't found any documentation on how to configure it neither in the Plugin's official documentation nor by searching Google.

Has anybody an Idea where to look or has anybody configured ACL Caching with Grails-Spring-Security-Acl before?

**Edit:**
We are using `grails-spring-security-acl v1.1` and `grails-spring-security-core v1.1.2`